# Show that there exist unbounded sequences, $x_n\neq y_n$, such that $x_n-y_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that there exist unbounded sequences, $x_n\neq y_n$, such that $x_n-y_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

How do I prove this? What sort of sequence would even satisfy this, if it is unbounded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Work backwards. Choose a sequence $z_n$ that tends to 0 and any unbounded sequence $y_n$. Define $x_n = y_n + z_n$. Then by construction $x_n - y_n = (y_n + z_n) - (y_n) = z_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is perhaps:
$$x_n=\sqrt{n+1}, \quad y_n=\sqrt n.$$

Comment: what about $n + \frac1n$ and $n$? :)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe none of those occurred to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

take $x_n = n + \frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n = n$, then $x_n - y_n = \frac{1}{n}$